# How to prove this is an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, linear-transformations

Be $\mathbb{K}$ a field, and $\alpha_0, \ldots , \alpha_n \in \mathbb{K}$ are distinct elements. Show the application
$$\mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq n} \to \mathbb{K}^{n+1}$$
$$p \mapsto (p(\alpha_0), \ldots, p(\alpha_n))$$
is an isomorphism.

**Attempts**

I proved the application is linear. Now I want to prove the application is injective, so I thought to look at the kernel, proving it's trivial.

The kernel contains all the polynomial of degree $n$ with the distinct roots, but I actually would prove it does contain only the trivial null vector, maybe proving the polynomials of degree $n$ with $n$ roots do not form a vector subspace...
Calling $f$ the application:

$$\ker (f) = \left\{ p \in \mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq n};\ \begin{pmatrix} p(\alpha_0) \\ \ldots \\ p(\alpha_n) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \ldots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{K}^{n+1} \right\}$$

So $\alpha_0, \ldots, \alpha_n$ are roots of the polynomial, that is $(x - \alpha_0)$, $(x - \alpha_1), \ldots $ divide $p$.

So if $p$ has $n$ roots, it won't be a polynomial of degree less than $n$ hence the kernel does contain either the polynomials of degree $n$ or the null polynomial.

If the kernel contains the poly of degree $n$ with $n$ roots (all with the same algebraic multiplicity) then all these polynomials are of the form $\beta (x - \alpha_0)(x-\alpha_1) \ldots (x-\alpha_n)$ hence all identical except for a multiplicative constant, whence $\ker(f) = span\{ (x-\alpha_0)\ldots (x-\alpha_n)\}$

I don't actually know how to proceed. We haven't dealt a lot with proofs, and being able to prove something is still quite hard for me...

I know that I also have to prove it's surjective which will imply the inverse does exist. Then I should prove both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. I don't really know where to start.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: You are on the right track when you invoke the fact that any polynomial of degree $n$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ has at most $n$ roots. Call the map given $f$ and suppose that $p \in \mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq n}$ is such that $f(p) = (0, 0, ..., 0)$. In other words, $p(\alpha_i) = 0$ for all $i = 0, 1, ..., n$. In other words, $p$ has $n+1$ distinct roots. Is this possible if $p$ is a non-zero polynomial?

Comment: For surjectivity, consider the case of $(1, 0, 0,..., 0)$. Can you find a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ such that $p(\alpha_0) = 1$ and $p(\alpha_i) = 0$ for all $i = 1, ..., n$? Once you have found such a polynomial $p$, can you extend it to other vectors of the form $(0,0,..,0,1,0,...0)$? Note that these vectors form a basis for $\mathbb{K}^{n+1}$, how does the linearity of $f$ help you then?

Comment: @HoWeiHaw Thank you! For the injective part, I would conclude it's not possible, I mean it's a contradiction. $p$ cannot have at most $n$ roots and $n+1$ distinct roots at the same time. Though I am missing the bridge that connects this fact, to the fact that only the zero polynomial lies in the kernel, if we require $p$ to have $n$ and $n+1$ roots at the same time...

Comment: @HoWeiHaw For surjectivity if I understood well, I can for example find $p = (x-1)x^n$ for the first idea, and ... like $p = x^{n-k} \cdot (x-1) \cdot x^{k}$? I will find a basis for $\mathbb{K}^{n+1}$ hence the image vectors fulfill $\mathbb{K}^{n+1}$ hence we have the surjectivity. The linearity though I don't know how it may help

Comment: We know that any nonzero polynomial $p \in \mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq n}$ has at most $\deg(p)$ roots where $0 \leq \deg(p) \leq n$. So, any nonzero polynomial $p$ cannot be mapped to the vector $(0,0, ..., 0)$ as this would mean that it has at least $n+1$ distinct roots, which is a contradiction. Hence, the only polynomial in $\mathbb{K}_{\leq n}$ that can be mapped to the vector $(0, 0, ..., 0)$ is?

Comment: For the surjectivity part, $p = (x-1)x^n$ would not work for 2 reasons.  Firstly, $p$ has degree $n + 1$ here and so $p \notin \mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq n}$. Secondly,   $p(\alpha_0) = (\alpha^n - 1)\alpha_0^n$ which need not be $1$ (the same reasoning applies for the other $\alpha_i$). 

Further hints:
How should a polynomial $p$ with roots $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n$ look like first? If we want $p(\alpha_0)$ to be $1$, how do we enforce that? Now, repeat this for the other vectors.

Comment: Finally, given any $(c_0, c_1, ..., c_n) \in \mathbb{K}^{n+1}$, we can write it as $c_0(1, 0, ..., 0) + c_1(0, 1, ..., 0) + ... + c_n(0, 0, ..., 0, 1)$. Since $f$ is linear, what can we do with the polynomials that we have found earlier?

Comment: Ok, so for the first thing: I understood only the null polynomial can be mapped to the null vector. 
About the surjectivity, a polynomial $p$ with such roots would be written as 

$$p = (x - \alpha_0)(x - \alpha_1) \ldots$$ hence if we want $p(\alpha_0) = 1$ we must require $p = (x - \alpha_0)^{n} + 1$ right? Or also $p = (x - \alpha_0)(x - \alpha_1) \ldots (x - \alpha_n) + 1$ Then we repeat.

Finally, I can say $f(c_k) = f(c_k(1, 0, \ldots )) = c_k f(1, 0, \ldots )$ for all $k$ from $1$ o $n$ hence the image is fulfilled (I know I say it bad, but I might have got it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150589/discussion-between-ho-wei-haw-and-numb3rs).

Comment: MSE is not a discussion forum. Please write answers and avoid lengthy discussions in the comments, which should only be used to clarify, not answer the problem.  See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is in the kernel then we know that it has $n+1$ distinct roots $\alpha_0,...,\alpha_n$. This means that $p \neq 0$ would immediately lead to a contradiction since a non zero polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n < n+1$ distinct roots.

This means that you must have $p \in \ker f \implies p = 0$ and the map is injective.

Moreover since $K[x]_{\leq n}$ and $K^{n+1}$ have the same dimension $n+1$ it follows that injective linear maps are always isomorphisms (this follows from the rank nullity theorem). Indeed we have

$$ rank(f) + \dim \ker f = n+1$$

so $rank(f) = n+1$. This means that the image of $f$ is an $n+1$ dimensional subsapce of $K^{n+1}$. That is,

$$ Im(f) = K^{n+1}$$

This proves that the map is a linear isomorphism.

---

In your post you also mention continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ this is of no interest for proving that we have isomorphism of vector spaces. However if you want to prove this too then it follows easily since linear maps are always continuous (and inverses of linear maps are also linear)

Comment: I'm missing why the dimension of $\mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq n}$ is $n+1$...

Comment: @Numb3rs Every element is a unique linear combination of $1,x,x^2,...,x^{n}$. That is, $1,x,x^2,...,x^n$ is a basis for that space.

Comment: Ah, that bloody $1$ haha, right... sigh.

Comment: @Numb3rs btw by similar arguments you would also have surjective -> isomorphism. In general if you have a linear map between spaces of equal dimension then proving either surjectivity or injectivity is sufficient to have an isomorphism.

Comment: Oh, this I didn't know... Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Numb3rs Again this is because of rank nullity. If the map is surjective then the rank nullity theorem forces $\dim \ker f = 0$ which mean $\ker f = 0$ so the map is injective.